# Namespace discrepancy in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two web projects using MVC (`ExampleProject`) and `ExampleProject.Two`), and a Domain model project (`ExampleProject.Domain`) that contains ViewModels. The ViewModels are shared between the two sites and both site projects reference the `ExampleProject.Domain` project.

I've noticed that for some reason ExampleProject can reference ExampleProject.Domain and use a ViewModel directly in the view, like so:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

However, ExampleProject.Two cannot do this, it must use a fully qualified name in order for the View to compile, like so:

```
@model ExampleProject.Domain.MyViewModel
```

I'm also using Bootstrap, and the following using directives are required inside the views for ExampleProject.Two. They are not required in ExampleProject. The Bootstrap libraries live independently in both sites.

```
@using TwitterBootstrap3
@using TwitterBootstrapMVC
```

Where should I start to figure out what exactly is going on here?

Comment: You probably want to add the appropriate namespaces to the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` section of your `web.config` (e.g. `<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />`).  You may have a `web.config` under the `Views` folder of your ExampleProject that has entries for `ExampleProject.Domain`.  Copy them to ExampleProject.Two

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I had forgotten about that.